# How can I check multiple conditions which single where clause in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter php framework. I have three category in the database namely :

1. category_name1
2. category_name2
3. category_name3

Now I want to use these three categories in WHERE clause in single function. For that I wrote some of those query, but none of this work:

The column name is category_name and values are above mentioned

```
$this->db->where('category_name','category_name1');
$this->db->or_where('category_name','category_name2');


$this->db->where('category_name','category_name1' or 'category_name2');
```

Now how can I use this?

Comment: Formatting your questions properly helps fellow members to understand your questions easily and help you better.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** try it this way

```
$this->db->where('category_name', $category_name1);
$this->db->or_where('category_name', $category_name2);
```

or

```
$this->db->where_in('category_name', $category_name1, $category_name2);
```

Comment: not working...$this->db->or_where('category_name','category_name2');....here category_name is my database column name & category_name1 is value of that column..

Comment: You should've mentioned this clearly in your question. Anyway see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use where_in as below:

```
$this->db->where_in('category_name', array($category_name1, $category_name2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $this->db->where('category_name',$category_name1)->where('category_name ',$category_name2)->where('category_name ',$category_name3);
```